# Refactoring Angular controller into separate factory and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, dependency-injection, angular-promise

Learning Angular. Working with `1.6.6` right now.

In my initial stab, I put all my `$http` requests into my controller, so I'm trying to pull that out of the controller and into a factory for more reusable code. I think that I am missing something related to `Promise` or injection, but the data from my `$http` call is not being bound to `$scope` correctly.

[I've been following along this guide.](https://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/)

I have a template that's begin loaded from the controller (the template is loading fine):

```
<form ng-init="getAllRegions()" ng-submit="getRandomTown()">

        <h3>Generate Random Town</h3>

        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="selectRegion">Select Region:</label>

            <select name="nameEntity"
                id="selectRegion"
                ng-model="guidEntity" 
                ng-options="item.guidEntity as item.nameEntity for item in regions">

                <option value="" ng-if="!guidEntity"></option>
            </select>
        </div>                                  
    </form>
```

The `ng-init` function is being called, and passes through the controller and the service. In chrome inspector I can see that data is pulling through correctly, but I'm new to working with `Promises`, so I'm losing something along the way. This was all working as expected when the `$http` call was right in the controller and the data was being bound to `$scope` in the controller.

The controller:

```
angular.
    module('randomTown.controller', []).

    component('randomTownGenerator', {

        templateUrl: 'js/components/randomTownGenerator/randomTownGenerator.tpl.html'

    }). 

    controller('RandomTownCtrl',

        function($scope, randomTownFactory) {

            $scope.data = {};

            $scope.getAllRegions = function () {
                $scope.regions = randomTownFactory.getAllDBRegions();
            }


        }
    );
```

The service:

```
angular.
    module('randomTown.service', []).
    factory('randomTownFactory', function ($q, $http) {

        var service = {};

        service.getAllDBRegions = function() {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: '/all-regions'
            }).then(function success(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }), function error(response) {
                deferred.reject('There was an error');
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return service;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer`. Simply return the `$http` promise:

```
app.factory('randomTownFactory', function ($q, $http) {

    var service = {};

    service.getAllDBRegions = function() {

        ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶q̶.̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶

        ̲r̲e̲t̲u̲r̲n̲ $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/all-regions'
        }).then(function success( ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ response) {
            ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶.̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶;̶
            return response.data;
        }),̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶(̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶

           ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶.̶r̶e̶j̶e̶c̶t̶(̶'̶T̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶'̶)̶;̶
        ̶}̶
          ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶.̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶;̶, 
    }

    return service;
});
```

Also notice that the `success` handler does not reveal the `data`. It reveals a `response` object of which `data` is one of the properties.

The controller:

```
app.controller('RandomTownCtrl',

    function($scope, randomTownFactory) {

        $scope.getAllRegions = function () {
            var promise = randomTownFactory.getAllDBRegions();
            promise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.regions = data;
            }).catch(function(errorResponse) {
                console.log("ERROR", errorResponse.status)
            });          
        }

    }
);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.getAllRegions = function () {
            randomTownFactory.getAllDBRegions()
            .then((regions) => {$scope.regions = regions});
        }
```

Why: because `etAllDBRegion`s returns a promise, so you have to use `then` property to get the result

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, and now I'm getting something in the drop-down where I want it, but all the values are `undefined`. I can see that the data is correct in `regions`, but it seems that binding to `$scope` is not working as I expect it should.

Comment: @NateAnderson - your options are empty: `<option value="" ng-if="!guidEntity"></option>`. try logging `regions` inside `then` and check what's inside

Comment: inside `then` regions is exactly what I'd expect. My understanding is that `ng-options="item.guidEntity as item.nameEntity for item in regions"` would suffice with `values=""`. Certainly is was working when the `$http` call was in the controller and the data was being bound directly.

Comment: @NateAnderson I'm not really sure, but there's no such example in docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions try removing this line at all. In case you have to use `ng-if` I'd recommend to use `nr-repeat` instead of `ng-options`